# A way to specify msbuild from which version of .net framework on Mac?

Tags: macos, msbuild, psake

Trying to create a build script using Psake on .Net Core 3 projects on Mac.

Invoking Psake with a specific framework,

```
Invoke-psake -buildFile default.ps1 `
             -taskList Test `
             -framework netcoreapp3.0 `
             -properties @{ 
                 "buildConfiguration" = "Release"
                 "buildPlatform" = "Any CPU"} `
             -parameters @{ 
                 "solutionFile" = "PaymentGateway.sln"}
```

and use msbuild for the solution.

```
Exec {
        msbuild $SolutionFile "/p:Configuration=$buildConfiguration;Platform=$buildPlatform;OutDir=$temporaryOutputDirectory"
    }
```

It doesn't compile. It seems to use 'mono msbuild', looking at the error message.

> "/Users/jakeryu/RiderProjects/PaymentGateway/PaymentGateway.sln" (default target) (1) ->
>   "/Users/jakeryu/RiderProjects/PaymentGateway/Bank/Bank.csproj" (default target) (8) ->
>     /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.18.1/lib/mono/msbuild/15.0/bin/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.TargetFrameworkInference.targets(137,5): error NETSDK1045: The current .NET SDK does not support targeting .NET Core 3.0.  Either target .NET Core 2.1 or lower, or use a version of the .NET SDK that supports .NET Core 3.0. [/Users/jakeryu/RiderProjects/PaymentGateway/Bank/Bank.csproj]

I have runtime and SDK installed for dotnetcore3 as below, and the current version is 3.0.100.

> dotnet --version
>   3.0.100

[image: dotnet --info]

I can't figure out why msbuild comes from the mono framework rather than .net core. Is there a way to specify which msbuild should be used on Mac?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `dotnet msbuild` as a drop-in replacement for `msbuild` to definitely use the MSBuild version coming with .NET Core.